# Segmentation fault(SIGSEGV) in my code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Im getting Segmentation fault(SIGSEGV) for many problems that iv solved in spoj and other websites. Im giving the problm statement link and code. Can anybody tell me the mistakes that iv done below.
Problem :
http://goo.gl/CVROl

Thanks in advance.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdio>
 #include<cstring> 
 #include<cmath>

 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a;
    string final,dummy;
    int t,h,p,k,z;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t)
    {
         cin>>a>>h>>p;
         final=a;
         for(int i=0;i<h;i++)
         {
              k=0;
              for(int j=0;final[j]!='\0';j++)
              {
                   if(final[j]=='a')
                   {
                        dummy[k]='a';
                        dummy[k+1]='b';
                        k+=2;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        dummy[k]='b';
                        dummy[k+1]='a';
                        k+=2;
                   }
              }
              final=dummy;
          }
          printf("%c\n",final[p-1]);
          t--;
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I don't see that there is memory allocated for 'dummy'.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by sstn, you did not allocate memory for dummy.  Since it's a string and it looks like you just want to append characters to it, you can do:

```
for(int j=0;j < final.size();j++)
{
    if(final[j]=='a')
    {
        dummy.push_back('a');
        dummy.push_back('b');
    }
    else
    {
        dummy.push_back('b');
        dummy.push_back('a');

    }
}
final=dummy;
```

Answer (score 0):

`final` is of type `std::string`, which aren't null terminated.

In your for loop: `for(int j=0;final[j]!='\0';j++)` you're checking for the end of the string as you would do in C (which a `char*` -- null terminated string), but in C++ you should iterate over string characters in some other ways: using an iterator, counting up the string size or something.

A fast quick to this problem (don't know whether there are others) is to get the null terminated `char*` representation of `final`: `final.c_str()` and iterater over it as you're doing.

Comment: Alternatively, `for(int j=0; j < final.size(); j++)` would do the trick I think.